# dotnet core, VS2017 15.5.4 is not publishing static html/js files from Ui folder

Tags: visual-studio-2017, .net-core

dotnet core 2.x, VS2017 15.5.4 is not publishing static html/js files from Ui folder.

We've combined out dotnet core Web Api and our Client UI, Aurelia into the same project.  When I publish the Aurelia files are not being copied out, only the files in the Aurelia that are json.  I thought I could right click the files and folders and set the Build Action property to Content but I get an error, see last image.

[image: Visual Studio 2017 15.5.4]
[image]

Here is my .csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>Web</AssemblyName>
    <RootNamespace>Web</RootNamespace>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>2.5</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="1.6.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile" Version="3.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.00" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Common\Common.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Lms\Lms.Service.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="appsettings.Development.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Error when right clicking and click Properties from the menu I get this
[image]

Comment: Serveable files in aspnetcore typically go in your wwwroot folder. You can [reconfigure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?tabs=aspnetcore2x) that if you want.

Comment: I don't want to serve these files.  These are source files that are compiled and the output is copied into the wwwroot/